# Reseting the email

Tags: javascript, php, json, reset

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make a reset password form. User would fill up the form with their username, which would connect to clients.json file, find the user and send them new email which would be generated. Somehow it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I'm sending the code so please let me know if you spot anything or if you have any tips on how to do it better. thanks!

```
<?php require_once 'top.php';

session_start();
$sUser = file_get_contents('../data/clients.json');
$jUser = json_decode($sUser);

$sForgotUserName = $_POST['txtForgotUserName'];
$sGeneratedPassword = rand(100000, 999999);

$jUser->data->{$sForgotUserName}->password = $sGeneratedPassword;

$sEmail = $jData->data->$sForgotUserName->email;

$sData = json_encode($jData);
    if ($sData == null) {
        sendResponse(0, __LINE__);
    }
    file_put_contents('../data/clients.json', $sData);


$from = "PETRABANK";
    $to = $sEmail;
    $subject = "Your New Password";
    $message = "Please use this password and then change it";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "The email message was sent.";

    ?>

<form id="frmForgotPassword" action="forgotpassword.php" method="POST">
    <input name="txtForgotUserName" id="txtUserName" type="text" placeholder="Your username">
    <button>Send new password</button>
</form>

<?php require_once 'bottom.php'?>
```

clients.json file

```
{
    "data": {
        "daniel": {
            "name": "dani",
            "lastName": "sss",
            "email": "s@hotmail.com",
            "password": "12345"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, After you decode json its been converted to array so that you can do like this replace the line `$jUser->data->{$sForgotUserName}->password = $sGeneratedPassword;` to `$jUser['data']['$sForgotUserName']['password'] = $sGeneratedPassword;` same as for email also and then after dump your `$jData` if your new credentials set to the array you have done you job.

Comment: Hi @Rits . So I used `$jUser['data']['$sForgotUserName']['password'] = $sGeneratedPassword;
$sEmail = ['$jUser']['data']['sForgotUserName']['email'];` but still does not work :/

Comment: have you dump after setting both values?

Comment: @Rits thanks for your help! Does dump mean to encode back? Well, I did `$jUser['data']['$sForgotUserName']['password'] = $sGeneratedPassword;
$sEmail = ['$jUser']['data']['sForgotUserName']['email'];

//$jUser->data->{$sForgotUserName}->password = $sGeneratedPassword;
//$sEmail = $jData->data->$sForgotUserName->email;

$sData = json_encode($jData);
    if ($sData == null) {
        sendResponse(0, __LINE__);
    }
    file_put_contents('../data/clients.json', $sData);`

Comment: Ah I can see that I used sUser and jUser while decoding and sDaa and jData while encoding. could that be the problem? I will fix it and see.

Comment: No no i mean just print it after setting those values by `print_r()`. if the array contains  your updates values then its done.

Comment: Hasn't done the job :/

Comment: change this to`$jData->data->$sForgotUserName->email` to `$jUser->data->$sForgotUserName->email` and please provide the output over here.

Comment: @Rits it worked with password! But doesn't display the email

Comment: so you wanted to update the email also with the new email?

Comment: @Rits I just wanted togenerate new email $sGeneratedPassword and send it to the email of user. Also, this password should replace his previous password in clients.json

Comment: then you can get that email by `$jUser['data'][$sForgotUserName]['email']` here you can get the email and send mail to that email.